# i am developing an app with node js , it works perfectly locally but crashes anytime i try to upload it to heroku,it says cat find dotenv

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, dotenv

i am developing an app with node js , it works perfectly locally but crashes anytime i try to upload it to heroku,it says Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv.i have installed it serval times and also updated my package but the problem continues, 
this is my package.json
`{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.9.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~4.1.1",
    "ejs": "~3.0.1",
    "ejs-mate": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.7.3",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.1",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "locus": "^2.0.4"
  }
}`

this is my Procfile
`web: node app.js`
this is my git ignore file
`/node_modules`
`.DS_Store`
`/*.env`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try movin `dotenv` from 'devDependencies' to 'dependencies'

Anything that is needed to actually run your app (lets call it "in production"), should be in 'dependencies'.

Anything that you may need while eg testing can be installed to 'devDependencies'

Comment: how do i do that , do i have to uninstall and install it back again ?

Comment: You could just edit the file manually and then run `npm install`